# Ordenar arrays en C

Tags: array, c

Tengo una función con la que se supone que debo unir y ordenar dos vectores en un tercero. El código sobre el trabajo:

```
void unir(int sol[], int *numSol, const int arrayA[], int numArraA, const int arrayB[], int numArraB){
    int i=0, j=0, s=0;
    while(i<numArraA&&j<numArraB){
        if(arrayA[i]<arrayB[j]){
            sol[s]=arrayA[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            sol[s]=arrayB[j];
            j++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    while(i<numArraA){
        sol[s]=arrayA[i];
        i++;
        s++;
    }
    while(j<numArraB){
        sol[s]=arrayB[j];
        j++;
        s++;
    }
    *numSol=s;
}
```

**Ambos vectores iniciales (arrayA, arrayB) están ya ordenados** por lo que no sé que me falla, solo muestra el primer dato de cada vector. Ejemplo:

*ArrayA: -1 2 3 5*

*Array B: 0 1 4*

El array que sale con este programa es:

*Sol: -1 0*

Debería ser:

*Sol: -1 0 1 2 3 4 5*

Comment: Yo tampoco sé qué te falla porque no lo has dicho. Por favor, edita la pregunta y describe el problema que tienes y lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que ese programa compila y puedes ejecutarlo? Porque un array en c no es un objeto al que le puedas pedir algo como `array.length`. Esto no te puede compilar... Tendrás que pasar como parámetros de la función la longitud de cada uno de los arrays para poder saber la longitud en la función.

Comment: No me da error, me salía un warning pero me dejaba ejecutar. Acabo de probar metiendo el numero de elementos de cada array y sale igual. Ahora actualizo el código a ver si está ahí el error.

Comment: No es necesario añadir Gracias y Solucionado a tu pregunta, el sistema te provee de dos herramientas para no meter ruido a la publicación: *agradecer => votar positivo* y *solucionado => aceptar una respuesta como válida*. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en los dos `while` del final.

Si te das cuenta, en la última vuelta del primer `while` incrementa la `s`, comprueba la condición y termina el `while`. Y justo lo primero que haces en los demás `while` es incrementar otra vez la `s`. Lo único que tendrías que hacer es cambiar de posición ese incremento:

```
while(i<numArraA){
    sol[s]=arrayA[i];
    i++;
    s++;
}
while(j<numArraB){
    sol[s]=arrayB[j];
    j++;
    s++;
}
//Ojo con esto que tenías puesto numSol= s y es el contenido lo que actualizas.
*numSol=s;
```

Comment: Sí, había cambiado cambiado la s por la i sin querrer.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!